# Behaviour of map emplace vs try_emplace?

Tags: c++, c++17

Let's say I have an unordered_map:

```
std::unordered_map<Key, BigObject> big_objects;
```

where `BigObject` is like:

```
struct BigObject {
    BigObject(P1, P2, P3); // <--- expensive
    /*...*/
};
```

and I have a `Key` `k`, and a set of arguments for `BigObject`s constructor `P1` `p1`, `P2` `p2` and `P3` `p3`.

If `big_objects` already contains `k` I want to do nothing.  If `big_objects` does not contain `K` I want to construct and insert `BigObject(p1,p2,p3)`

Is it possible to do this with a single lookup on `big_objects`?

ie Will `emplace` or `try_emplace` construct `BigObject` if the key is already present?

**Update**

After some testing it seems like `emplace` does construct `BigObject` but `try_emplace` doesn't ?

ie

```
big_objects[k] = BigObject(p1,p2,p3) // insert k, k now present...

big_objects.emplace(k, p1, p2, p3); // does construct a BigObject

big_objects.try_emplace(k, p1, p2, p3); // does not construct a BigObject
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is correct, this is the reason why `try_emplace` exists, it doesn't touch its arguments if the key is already present.

[Cppreference `try_emplace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/try_emplace)

> Unlike insert or emplace, these functions do not move from rvalue arguments if the insertion does not happen, which makes it easy to manipulate maps whose values are move-only types, such as std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr>. In addition, try_emplace treats the key and the arguments to the mapped_type separately, unlike emplace, which requires the arguments to construct a value_type (that is, a std::pair)

As a bonus point, you do not have to use the ugly `std::piecewise_construct` tag to pass both the key and the value constructor arguments ( unless you want to inplace construct the key too).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, like this algorithm problem：
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXxTb.png)

One solution is：

```
int findShortestSubArray(vector<int>& nums) 
{
    std::unordered_map<int, std::tuple<int, int, int>> map;
    int s = nums.size();
    for(int i = 0; i < s; ++i)
    {
        if(!map.try_emplace(nums.at(i), std::tuple<int, int, int>{1,i,i}).second)
        {
            ++std::get<0>(map.at(nums.at(i)));
            std::get<2>(map.at(nums.at(i))) = i;
        }                
    }
    //...
}
```

This solution takes the result of its execution from the return value of `try_emplace()` and uses it as a condition for an if statement， end up with a very nice space-time overhead:

> Execution Time: 32ms, beating 97.50% of users in all C++ commits
> Memory consumption: 24.3MB, beating 93.47% of users in all C++ commits

but if I replace `try_emplace()` with `emplace()`, Space-time costs will balloon:

> Execution Time: 84ms, beating 61.24% of users in all C++ commits
> Memory consumption: 33.8MB, beating 6.65% of users in all C++ commits

This reason has been answered by other friends, and I think that's a good example of the difference between the two.